# Splitting the Real Line

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

By definition a $\mathfrak c$-dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has $\mathfrak c$-sized intersection with every non-empty open set. Using transfinite recursion it is quite easy to prove that every $\mathfrak c$-dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$-many $\mathfrak c$-dense subsets.

I am wondering if there are other (more elementary) proofs of this, perhaps one that doesn't use transfinite recursion, but some raw form of AC?

Comment: The "raw form of AC" is like a steak knife. It is almost entirely useless for eating a very large steak, unless you have a fork called "transfinite recursion". Sure, though, you can do it with Zorn's lemma.

Comment: What is the mechanism by which a subset of $\Bbb  R$ partitions $\Bbb R$ into many subsets?

Comment: @Greg: This is more delicate than just that. It's partitioning a dense subset of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ into $2^{\aleph_0}$ dense subsets. The proof is essentially the construction of a Bernstein set.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll clarify the wording so that others aren't confused like I was.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what sort of answer you're expecting to have. What form of AC would you like to see used? Every vector space has a basis? Various model theoretic statements? Zorn's lemma?

Comment: Zorn's lemma would do, it is more elementary to me than recursion. How do you prove it via ZL?

Comment: It took some thinking, but I like the resulting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this using Zorn's lemma.

Fix a $\frak c$-dense set $A$. Now consider the following partial order $\Bbb P$ whose elements are $S$ such that:

1. $S$ is a partition of a subset of $A$.
   and for every $X\in S$, we have:
2. $|X|=|S|$.
3. $X$ is $|X|$-dense.
4. $A\setminus X$ is $\frak c$-dense.

We say that $S_1\leq S_2$ if and only if the following is true:

1. For every $X\in S_1$ there is a unique $Y\in S_2$ such that $X\subseteq Y$, and
2. For every $Y\in S_2$ there is at most one $X\in S_1$ such that $X\subseteq Y$.

Now suppose that $\{S_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a chain. Then there is an obvious upper bound, since each $X_i\in S_i$ has a unique extension in every other $S_j$ for $i<j$, we simply take the union over these unique extensions. Let $S$ be the obtained partition.

It is easy to see that if indeed $S\in\Bbb P$, then $S_i\leq S$ for every $i\in I$. So it suffices to show that $S\in\Bbb P$.

1. $S$ is a partition of $\bigcup S\subseteq A$ is trivial.
2. The cardinality of $S$ is $\sup|S_i|\cdot |I|$, and each $X\in S$ is the $|I|$-union of $X_i$'s whose cardinality is $|S_i|$ as well. So we get that $X$ has the wanted cardinality as well.
3. If $X\in S$ and $(a,b)$ is an open set, then $X\cap(a,b)=\bigcup X_i\cap(a,b)$, and since each $X_i$ is $|X_i|$-dense, this union gives us again that $X$ is $|X|$-dense.
4. Finally the last part is also easy, if $|X|<\frak c$, then of course that $A\setminus X$ is $\frak c$-dense by obvious cardinal arithmetic. If $|X|=\frak c$, then $|S|=\frak c$, and every $Y\in S$ is already $\frak c$-dense, so $\bigcup S\setminus\{X\}$ is a subset of $A\setminus X$ witnessing that it is $\frak c$-dense.

Now comes the easiest part. Using Zorn's lemma we obtain a maximal element $S$. If $|S|=\frak c$, then we are done, since this gives us the wanted partition. Otherwise $S$ cannot be maximal, since $A\setminus\bigcup S$ is $\frak c$-dense, pick from every interval with rational endpoints a subset of $A\setminus\bigcup S$ of size $|S|$, and this allows extending $S$ by another part so it is not maximal.

Comment: Can you can show if ZF + DC cannot prove this? It seems interesting because Solovay's model doesn't work.

Comment: I had a guess about this (and originally I read the question as asking how to do it without choice). I'm thinking that probably you can show that the perfect set property ensures that this doesn't happen. Namely, if you split a $\frak c$-dense set into $\frak c$ parts, they cannot all have the perfect set property. Then you show that this cannot happen. But the intermediate part seems like your kind of argument, that this sort of partition at least one of the parts cannot have the perfect set property. Is that true?

Comment: I meant to say that ZF + DC + Perfect set property does imply that every c-dense set can be partitioned into c many c-dense sets so this is true in Solovay's model. So the failure, if at all consistent with ZF + DC, will require some other model.

Comment: Well, $\sf ZF+DC$ is consistent with $\Bbb R$ can be well-ordered, so you know. I'm still not entirely following your first statement. $\sf ZF+DC+PP$ implies that you cannot partition $\frak c$-dense sets, or are you asking whether this is the case?

Comment: I was trying to say that if ZF + DC + "there is a c-dense set of reals that cannot be partitioned into c many c-dense sets" is consistent, then a witnessing model would also satisfy the failure of both "PP" and "the set of reals cannot be well ordered".

Comment: Why would it satisfy the failure of $\sf PP$?

Comment: Assume PP. Let X be a c-dense set of reals. Let $\langle P_n : n < \omega  \rangle$ be a list of perfects subsets of X intersected with all rational intervals. Let $\langle Q_n : n < \omega \rangle$ be a disjoint refinement (so $Q_n \subseteq P_n$ is perfect and $Q_n$'s are pairwise disjoint). Now partition each $Q_n$ into continuum many perfect sets and put one piece in each set. All of this should be doable in ZF + DC.

Comment: Why can you partition $Q_n$ into continuum many perfect sets?

Comment: Since $Q_n$ contains a copy of $2^{\omega}$, it is enough to partition $2^{\omega}$ into continuum many perfect sets. For each $x \in 2^{\omega}$, let $P_x$ be the set of all members of $2^{\omega}$ whose restrictions to even bits agrees with $x$. Then $\{P_x : x \in 2^{\omega} \}$ is the desired partition. I hope this all works out with dependent choice.

Comment: Okay, suppose that this part works out; I still don't see how you can get more than countably many sets at the end. Your plan is to choose from each $Q_n$ a perfect subset and then take the union, sure. That work once, that work countably many times using $\sf DC$. But how can you push this to the continuum without having some well-ordering on the continuum?

Comment: Once we have disjoint collections $\langle T_{n, x} : x \in 2^{\omega} \rangle$ of perfects subsets of $Q_n$, we can put $W_x = \bigcup \{T_{n, x} : n < \omega\}$. $\{W_x : x \in 2^{\omega} \}$ is a family of continuum many c-dense subsets of X.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that seems to work just fine. It's an interesting problem. I wonder if $\sf ZF+PP+\lnot DC$ would be a way to solve this; and if not whether having the continuum as a countable union of countable sets will work.

Comment: I just realized that all I wrote above shows that ZF + DC is sufficient to partition every c-dense set into c many c-dense sets by working on the indexing of X. I have no intuition about countable choice free worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite method to pick (say) an almost disjoint family $A$ of infinite sets of integers. For each $x \in A$, let $W_x$ be the set of all reals whose binary expansion eventually agrees with $x$ on every other coordinate.

-hq

p.s. Forgot to say, $A$ has size continuum.

Comment: I just noticed that I misread the question. I guess this only works for splitting a set which meets every interval on a perfect set. Maybe Asaf can justify the necessity of the use a well ordering of reals here.